# Creating an HTMLDocument from a String of HTML (in Java)

Tags: java, html, string, dom

I'm working on a method that takes a String of HTML and returns an analogous

```
 javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

The way I'm currently doing this is to use a SAX parser to parse the HTML string.  I keep track of when I hit open tags (for example, <i>).  When I hit the corresponding close tag (for example, </i>), I apply the italics style to the characters I've hit in between.

This certainly works, but it's not fast enough.  Is there a faster way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `HtmlEditorKit` class. It supports parsing of HTML content that can be read directly from `String` (e.g. through `StringReader`). [There seems to be an article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31059) about how to do this.

Edit: To give an example, basically I think it could be done like this (aftrer the code is executed, `htmlDoc` should contain the loaded document...):

```
Reader stringReader = new StringReader(string);
HTMLEditorKit htmlKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
HTMLDocument htmlDoc = (HTMLDocument) htmlKit.createDefaultDocument();
HTMLEditorKit.Parser parser = new ParserDelegator();
parser.parse(stringReader, htmlDoc.getReader(0), true);
```

Comment: This looks correct, but doesn't seem to be working.  Consider this test case:
    public void testMakeHTMLDocument() throws Exception {
  final String hTML = "<html>\n"
   + "<body>\n"
   + "\n"
   + "<h1>My First Heading</h1>\n"
   + "\n"
   + "<p>My first paragraph.</p>\n"
   + "\n"
   + "</body>\n"
   + "</html>";
  final HTMLDocument htmlDocument =
   MyHTMLDocumentLoader.makeHTMLDocument(hTML);
  htmlDocument.dump(System.out);
 }

Comment: It dumps this:<html
  name=html
>
  <body
    name=body
  >
    <p
      margin-top=0
      resolver=NamedStyle:default {name=default,}
      name=p
    >
      <content
        name=content
      >
        [0,1][
]
<bidi root>
  <bidi level
    bidiLevel=0
  >
    [0,1][
]

Comment: I'm a little-bit afraid that this is because of the weakness of HTML support by `HTMLEditorKit`; according to javadoc, "The default support is provided by this class, which supports HTML version 3.2 (with some extensions), and is migrating toward version 4.0" -- I'm afraid you'll need to handle the tags manually in the callback -- not sure if this is somehow better than your original approach :(

Answer (score 11):

Agree with mouser but a small correction

```
Reader stringReader = new StringReader(string);
HTMLEditorKit htmlKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
HTMLDocument htmlDoc = (HTMLDocument) htmlKit.createDefaultDocument();
htmlKit.read(stringReader, htmlDoc, 0);
```

Comment: This really worked for me, the selected answer did not.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the [`HTMLDocument.setOuterHTML`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.html#setOuterHTML%28javax.swing.text.Element,%20java.lang.String%29) method. Simply add a random element and replace it afterwards with your HTML string.

Comment: Just don't forget that: 'For this to work correcty, the document must have an HTMLEditorKit.Parser set. This will be the case if the document was created from an HTMLEditorKit via the createDefaultDocument method.'