# Confusion while importing java packages in IDE(eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, class, namespaces, package

I am facing a small issue.

I have to create an HTML document for few operations on random HTML pages. For that I have to create an object as shown below:

```
HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument)kit.createDefaultDocument();
```

Here, my IDE (Eclipse) suggests me to import files where class of type "HTMLDocument" is defined. But it's suggesting 2 package which has this class.

1. `import'HTMLDocument'` (javax.swing.text.HTML)
2. `import'HTMLDocument'` (org.w3c.doc.HTML)

Importing any one package will remove the error from my program file in eclipse. But am confused which package will serve my purpose.

Is there a way I can figur eout which package to import?

Comment: Check the package and select whichever you want to use based on your requirement

Comment: I think you need this: `import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;` if kit is `HTMLEditorKit`

Comment: 1. How do i check the package? 2. Even if i check how will i know which package will provides good functions as my needs might keep on increasing/changing?

Comment: You should check Java documentation of this two classes and decide, which one suits best for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your kit object is javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit, you must use javax.swing.text.html package.
If not you should read java documentation and find out your program need.

Below link will also help you.

[Creating an HTMLDocument from a String of HTML (in Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698057/creating-an-htmldocument-from-a-string-of-html-in-java)